# Concatenate multiple variables isn't working

Tags: bash

I have these variables:

$reel = XF_1

$base = AA000201

$output_dir = directory

This command isn't working.  It produces a file called directory/AA000201.mp4

```
ffmpeg -i $1 $output_dir"/$reel_$base.mp4
```

This command works.  It produces a file called directory/XF_1_AA000201.mp4.

```
ffmpeg -i $1 $output_dir"/"$reel"_"$base".mp4"
```

But it gives this error: /Volumes/RAID/LIGHTS/RawFootage/Day01/B_Camera/XF_1/CONTENTS/CLIPS001/AA0002/AA000201.MXF: line 5: continue: only meaningful in a `for',`while', or `until' loop

Note: I have shortened directory names here for simplicity.

Comment: Oops.  I realized the error was unrelated.  Both commands work fine.  Can someone please delete this question?

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg -i "${1}" "${output_dir}/${reel}_${base}.mp4"
```

Answer (score 1):

Polbrelkey gave you the answer, but i'm still gonna add this.

Lets see why `ffmpeg -i $1 $output_dir"/$reel_$base.mp4` is un-interpretable unambiguously :

Look at those three variables :

```
reel="A"
reel_="B"   #Nothing prevents you from ending a variable with an underscore
base="C"
```

Now, let's interpret `ffmpeg -i $1 $output_dir"/$reel_$base.mp4` : 
Depending on how your decompose the string, you get either :

```
#ffmpeg -i $1 $output_dir"/${reel_}${base}.mp4
ffmpeg -i $1 $output_dir"/BC.mp4    

#ffmpeg -i $1 $output_dir"/${reel}_${base}.mp4
ffmpeg -i $1 $output_dir"/A_C.mp4
```

In your case, Bash is actually interpreting the first one (actually, he looks for the longest possible variable name) and since `reel_=""` is not assigned, outputs `directory/AA000201.mp4`.
You don't have these kind of problems with `base.mp4` since a variable name can't have a dot.

Source : [Parameter Expansion on Bash-Hackers](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#simple_usage)